# Can too-large images cause Error Establishing a Database Connection

Tags: errors

My client's site has a number of large (300 - 500 KB) images on the home page.  Lately, they've been increasing the size and number of these.  At the same time, they are starting to see the 'Error Establishing a Database Connection' message when there is higher traffic to the site.

I've looked at a number of the reasons that can cause the database error, but none that say that a high load, by way of many large images, is a culprit.

Is this possible, or should I dig deeper for the reason?

(Of course, we're deactivating plugins to see if they are a factor).  (And, of course, I've preached to them, constantly, to optimize these images!)

Thank you.

Comment: I am very sure it's the hosting issue.. is it shared hosting ??

Answer (score 0):

No - the size of the images has absolutely nothing to do with the "Error Establishing a Database Connection" message.